# Couple questions about uninstalling Magento Extension

Tags: extensions, magento-connect

I found this uninstall tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T63JZNT9MM8

Is that the only thing I would need to do? Would it be completely deleted?

And if I want to use the extension in the future, would I need to Install again? Or I can use the "reinstall" option. If so, that means the extension would not be completely gone right?

Comment: yes if you didn't make changes yourself and if the extension didn't changed your database. If you want to install it again after to have uninstalled it, you will have to install as it is the first time you do an install. DO ALWAYS A BACKUP OF YOUR DB BEFORE TO DO ANYTHING. my 50cts

Comment: Ok, great thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the uninstall part of the connect but there are a few things to note.

1. If the extension has added any attributes or anything to the database they will not remove. You could easily create a module specifically for removing these attributes via a setup script. Or add one final setup script the the module before removing it,
2. Not all modules will show up in the list only the ones that have been installed via magento connect and contain a file under `var\package`,
3. After remove you should check that there is not an entry for this extension under the table `core_resource`